# Splitting Association Rules output text files into column

Tags: r

I have a text files saving my association rules, so I used read.table to read the file and then store it into a matrix. The text files data are as below

```
10 <- 8 3 (7,0.318182)
3 <- 8 10 (7,0.4375)
8 <- 3 10 (7,1)
```

I used subset to break the rules and now I have three column of data like this.

```
V1         V2        V3
10 <- 8 3   7    0.318182
3 <- 8 10   7    0.4375
8 <- 3 10   7    1
```

I try to break the V1 and stores only the number in a new matrix but I have error. When i check foo[1,2] I get a result

```
[1]  8 3
Levels: 8 3
```

Here is my code. I need some help in breaking all these value then store it in a matrix.

```
rules = read.table("C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/rules 1.txt",header = FALSE, quote = "\"", sep = ",")
N<-nrow(rules)
trans= subset(rules, select=c("V1"))
foo <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(a),'<-',fixed=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` package, and `gsub` to split the first column,

```
library(splitstackshape)
df1 <- cSplit(data.frame(a = gsub('<-', '', df$V1)), 'a', ' ', 'wide')
df1
#   a_1 a_2 a_3
#1:  10   8   3
#2:   3   8  10
#3:   8   3  10
```

If you want to bind them, then,

```
cbind(df1, df[,-1])
#   a_1 a_2 a_3 V2       V3
#1:  10   8   3  7 0.318182
#2:   3   8  10  7 0.437500
#3:   8   3  10  7 1.000000
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c("10 <- 8 3", "3 <- 8 10", "8 <- 3 10"), 
    V2 = c(7L, 7L, 7L), V3 = c(0.318182, 0.4375, 1)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: As the `splitstackshape` output is a data.table, you could use `data.table` methods to bind with the original dataset

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand entirely, but you can get those first three numbers in separate columns if you define `sep` to be a space.

```
> rules = read.table(text = text, header = FALSE, quote = "\"", sep = " ")
> rules
  V1 V2 V3 V4           V5
1 10 <-  8  3 (7,0.318182)
2  3 <-  8 10   (7,0.4375)
3  8 <-  3 10        (7,1)
```

I'd recommend `separate` from `tidyr` to split any remaining columns further.

Comment: `read.table(text=text)` also gives that result. I don't know where the OP is getting what they're seeing...

Answer (score 0):

so that's how I'd do it. Let's say you have your data in a file called 'tmp.txt'. You can read all the lines of this file with:

```
data = readLines("tmp.txt")
```

This will create an array that has on the i-th element the i-th line of your text file. So that `data[i]` looks like this:

```
[1] "10 <- 8 3 (7,0.318182)"
```

You now want to create a parsing function that can be applied to all the elements of this array and that returns as output a matrix with all the data nicely formatted. This should do the job:

```
parse_string = function(x){
  first_element = as.numeric(gsub(" .*", "", x))
  second_element = as.numeric(gsub(" .*", "", gsub(".* <- ", "", x)))
  third_element = as.numeric(gsub(" .*", "", gsub(".* <- [0-9]* ", "", x)))
  fourth_element = as.numeric(gsub(",.*", "", gsub(".*\\(", "", x)))
  fifth_element = as.numeric(gsub("\\).*", "", gsub(".*,", "", x)))
  matrix(c(first_element, second_element, third_element, fourth_element, fifth_element), nrow = 1)
}
```

If you run the `parse_string(data[1])` for instance you get:

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]     [,5]
 [1,]   10    8    3    7 0.318182
```

Finally you can run the `parse_string` on all the vector and bind together the results with:

```
lapply(data, parse_string) %>% do.call(rbind)
```

and this should give you the desired matrix as output:

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]     [,5]
 [1,]   10    8    3    7 0.318182
 [2,]    3    8   10    7 0.437500
 [3,]    8    3   10    7 1.000000
```

Comment: Hi, I have try the code, but when I run `parse_string(data[1])` I get
 `> parse_string(rules[1])
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]     [,5]
[1,]   10    8    3   NA 0.318182`
NAs are introduced. If i have more than 5 elements than I have to add more element in the parse functions?